# Server responds to an IP address which is not assigned

Tags: networking, debian, ip-address, ifconfig

I have a rather out-of-date debian server, which has only one assigned IP address - 10.1.1.2 - this address is assigned manually in /etc/network/interfaces

However, I just discovered that the server responds to the IP address 10.1.1.49 as well.

ifconfig and ip addr only show two interfaces **lo** and **eth0**. There are no obvious aliases. The server has only **one** physical ethernet port as well.

Recursive grepping through the /etc folder yields no files with the 10.1.1.49 IP address.

I can ping, ssh, get apache responses, and so forth through this "ghost" IP address.

The router has no forwarding or anything similar for this IP address, the address is outside of the DHCP pool and is not assigned.

I assume the server is somehow compromised, but absolutely no tools show 
anything suspicious.
Any ideas?

EDIT: The machine runs on an old board - Intel D945GCLF2 - there is no AMT or vPro which caused similar issues (at least what I could find)

EDIT2: More data

arp for both addresses is the same

```
[root@bman ~]# cat /proc/net/arp  | grep 00:1c:c0:ef:88:a5
10.1.1.2         0x1         0x2         00:1c:c0:ef:88:a5     *        enp7s0
10.1.1.49        0x1         0x2         00:1c:c0:ef:88:a5     *        enp7s0
```

ifconfig -a output

```
biric:# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:c0:ef:88:a5  
          inet addr:10.1.1.2  Bcast:10.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21c:c0ff:feef:88a5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3715031017 errors:0 dropped:3576479642 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2284866989 errors:0 dropped:1518 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:676181967 (644.8 MiB)  TX bytes:3904143166 (3.6 GiB)
          Interrupt:220 Base address:0x8000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:44284259 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:44284259 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4218796581 (3.9 GiB)  TX bytes:4218796581 (3.9 GiB)
```

ip addr show output

```
biric:# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:c0:ef:88:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.1.2/24 brd 10.1.1.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::21c:c0ff:feef:88a5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: How have you determined that it is the same box?

Comment: Yes, it is 100% the same box, like I said ssh-ing to both IPs gets me on the same box.

Comment: What is the output of `ip addr show` or `ifconfig -a`? Are the ARP table entries for both IP addresses the same? I assume you are connecting to the box from the same subnet.

Comment: I updated the opening post, arp table entries are the same, I am connecting from the same subnet (my IP is 10.1.1.XX, subnet is 10.1.1.1/24)

Comment: Check for a firmware update for the nic. Maybe even just try re-applying the same firmware version as it may be corrupted. I've seen a whole product line of 4g-wifi/ethernet routers, where the device would respond to ALL ARP requests no matter what IP was being requested, claiming that it had that IP. This would fairly quickly break our network as it stole all the IP addresses. The company could have released a firmware update to fix it, but they never did.